# Shiny App Desktop Deployment Package Issue?

Tags: r, deployment, package, shiny

So i'm trying to deploy a Shiny app that i made following the instructions that i found in the R-blogger website using Chrome Portable and R portable. My issue is that after I started using the DT package my app is encountering an error (I guess) because my outputbox for the table are not rendering anything anymore, I did install the 'DT' package in R portable so I don't understand where this is coming from. (By the way I don't know and understand anything about the way this app is deployed I only followed the instructions and it worked once i don't understand what changed this time)

Here is my log if it can help you (French sorry):

Le chargement a nécessité le package : shiny
Le chargement a nécessité le package : methods

Listening on http://127.0.0.1:7777

Attaching package: 'shinydashboard'

The following object is masked from 'package:graphics':

```
box
```

Attaching package: 'DT'

The following objects are masked from 'package:shiny':

```
dataTableOutput, renderDataTable
```

[1] "C:/Users/p-haffoud/Documents/TestApp/shiny"

Ok so here is my ui:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

shinyUI(dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title="Type Arret"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Maladie Ordinaire", tabName = "MO", icon = icon("plus-square")),
      menuItem("Longue Maladie", tabName = "LM", icon = icon("clock-o")),
      menuItem("Longue Duree", tabName = "LD", icon = icon("hourglass")),
      menuItem("Total", tabName = "Tot", icon = icon("arrow-right"))
       )
  )
  ,
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(tabName = "MO",
        fluidRow(
          img(src='SMACL.jpg',length=75,width=150, align = "right"),
          column(8,
             titlePanel(
               tags$h1("Proportion des jours d'arrets",style="font-family:Impact"))
          )),

        wellPanel(
          fluidRow(column(3,
                          numericInput(inputId = "numMO",
                                       label = "Jour limite",
                                       value = 10, min = 1, max=1000),
                          actionButton(inputId="clicksMO",
                                       label= "Actualiser")))),
        wellPanel(
          fluidRow(
            dataTableOutput("tableMO"))))




     )
   )

))
```

And here is my server file :

```
library(DT)

print(getwd())
DFSurvieMO <- read.csv2("data/DFSurvMO.csv",check.names=FALSE)
DFSurvieMO <-DFSurvieMO[,c(2,3,4,6)]

shinyServer(
  function(input, output, session){
    session$onSessionEnded(function() {
      stopApp()
    })

  numerMO <- eventReactive(input$clicksMO , {(which(abs(DFSurvieMO[,1]-input$numMO)==min(abs(DFSurvieMO[,1]-input$numMO)))[1])})

  valeurnumer <- eventReactive(input$clicks, {
    (numer())
  })

  output$tableMO <- DT::renderDataTable({
    datatable(DFSurvieMO,
              options = 
                list( displayStart= numerMO()-2,
                      pageLength = 15,
                      lengthChange = FALSE, searching =FALSE),rownames= FALSE) %>% formatStyle(
      c(1:2),
      backgroundColor = 
        if(numerMO()>1) {
          styleInterval(c(DFSurvieMO[,1][numerMO()-1],DFSurvieMO[,1][numerMO()]), c('blank','lightblue', 'blank'))
        }
        else {
          styleInterval(DFSurvieMO[,1][numerMO()], c('lightblue', 'blank'))}

      )
    })
  })
```

The data that i refer to are simply some csv tables with numeric values, the first is the time in days. The four others are 3 integers and 1 double even though i doubt it changes anything.

Thank you.

Comment: Please add a small reproducible example of your app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so apparently the answer was extremely simple after 2 days looking into it I think that the issue was simply that I didn't call the libraries on both the ui AND the server files. So by simply putting the three calls to the libraries (DT,shiny and shinydashboard) on both files it seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

In order to follow the Don't Repeat Yourself (DRY) rule, you also might want to consider moving the `library` calls to your global.R file in the same directory as ui.R and server.R. That way you will only need to update them in one place.